# Strapi upload image url in collection types

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, upload, strapi

How can i upload image URL to Strapi collection types and I want to update the field
I have tried various methods to upload but didn't got the result can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In strapi to upload the image, first you have to use /uploads request and pass file in bytes as an request body.
Use the response of this API as an field value of image.

Suppose, you have products collection which has attribute called image and its datatype is media.
To store image into this attribute,
first call /uploads API and pass request body as "files":image-bytes and response from this /uploads API is used when you try to store image in product.

While creating the product, inside image attribute use /uploads API response.
And you are done.